# How to implement jqGrid with Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, jqgrid, marionette

I am trying to render jqGrid in my Marionette application, everything goes fine until I cannot find the way to render the pager.
I am using Handlebars that holds the template, this is the code:

```
hb template:
    <script id='llantas_grid_tmpl' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
        <table id='llantas_catalog_list'></table>
        <div id="llantas_catalog_pager">pager</div>
    </script>


layout...


    ui: {
            table: '#llantas_catalog_list',
            pager: '#llantas_catalog_pager'
        },

    onRender: function(){
            var table           = this.ui.table,
                pager           = this.ui.pager;          

            table

                .jqGrid({
                    url: '/llantas',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames:['Id','Orden De Compra', 'Marca', 'Medida', 'Modelo'],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
                        {name:'ordencompra',index:'ordencompra', width:90},
                        {name:'marca',index:'marca', width:90},
                        {name:'medida',index:'medida', width:90},
                        {name:'modelo',index:'modelo', width:90}
                    ],
                    rowNum:10,
                    rowList:[10,20,30],
                    pager: '#llantas_catalog_pager',
                    width:1060,
                    height:375,
                    sortname: 'id',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    caption:"<h3>Catalogo llantas<h3>"
                });

            table
                .jqGrid('navGrid','#llantas_catalog_pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});    

        }
```

is there a way to set the pager placeholder into the jqGrid as object?
like this:

```
table
.jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

EDIT: PLEASE ANSWER ONLY IF YOU KNOW BACKBONE MARIONETTE AND JQGRID.

Comment: What is the value of `pager`?

Comment: it's a jQuery object from the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, No.

[jqGrid does a check](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/f3d9f49a54dbdce432f3c04a4303cc69e70dd841/js/grid.formedit.js#L1749) to make sure it is a string,

```
if(!$t.grid || typeof elem !== 'string') {return;}
```

You would need to modify the jqGrid source.

Comment: Actually it does allow to pass an object I have just read the docs:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties
"The valid calls can be (using our example) 'pager', '#pager', jQuery('#pager'). I recommend to use the second one."

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make it work:

Once the child view (the one I was trying to render with jqGrid) has been rendered and displayed in the region of the main view I just search for the template table selector and pass the pager id inside the jqGrid pager option.

main layout...

```
onRender: function(){

        // llantasGridView is the view holding only the template without the jqGrid (I erased everything)    
        var llantasGridView = new LlantasGrid.View();

        // table_container is the region that will hold the llantasGridView template
        this.table_container.show( llantasGridView );

        // once is rendered I search for the table
        var table = llantasGridView.$el.find('#llantas_catalog_list');

        // here I pass the jqGrid 
        table
            .jqGrid({
                url: G.API + '/llantas',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames:['Id','PO'...

                pager: '#llantas_catalog_pager', // pager for grid is now being displayed
...
```

Comment: when rendering the jqgrid do you render it in Itemview or collection view, I am thinking both of these are not suitable , shall i use the view that extend regular Backbone view ?